# stuck at install edumeet media node on docker

Tags: webrtc, mediasoup

I clone edumeet-media-node project (https://github.com/edumeet/edumeet-media-node) to my ubuntu.
I check port 3000, 40000-40249 are available and I allow: port 3000,40000-40249 on ufw.

Next, I run 2 commands:

```
docker build . -t edumeet-media-node

docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 40000-40249:40000-40249/udp -p 40000-40249:40000-40249/tcp edumeet-media-node --ip [public IP] --secret asd9dkd93js0kmd7sds76sdf
```

At the step run container, I have an error:

```
MediaNode MediaService creation failed: Error: port bind failed due to address not available [transport:udp, ip:'[public IP]', port:40165, attempt:1/250].
```

is there any way to fix the bug?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node process can't bind to public IP of host inside the container.
You could use host networking in docker instead.

`docker run --network=host edumeet-media-node --ip [public IP] --secret asd9dkd93js0kmd7sds76sdf`

Official documentation has now been updated to use host networking.
https://github.com/edumeet/edumeet-media-node

Comment: Yes I already give public IP

Comment: @khoivu https://github.com/edumeet/edumeet-media-node/issues/19

Comment: @khoivu please let me know if you managed to run media-node service with host networking.

Comment: thanks for your support. I have run it with network host